# hugo how to sort tags and categories in terms.html

Tags: sorting, tags, categories, hugo

Following the documentation, I have my `layouts/_default/terms.html` template which looks like this:

```
{{ range .Pages }}
<li>
    <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
</li>
{{ end }}
```

My tags or categories (depending on if I'm on `/tags/` or `/categories/`) list all the tags/categories but not in alphabetical order.

How to sort them ? I have tried to add the `sort` keyword like this `{{ range sort .Pages }}` but it doesn't work. Any idea how to sort them by `.Title` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the property to sort on to the [`sort` function](https://gohugo.io/functions/sort/). Since you're iterating over a list of tag pages, you probably want to use the titles of the pages (which are the tag names):

```html
{{ range (sort .Pages "Title") }}
<li>
    <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
</li>
{{ end }}
```

If you want the list to be in the opposite order, pass `"desc"` to the `sort` function as the third argument.

Answer (score 2):

Less clutter:

```
{{range .Pages.ByTitle}} 
<li>
    <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
</li>
{{ end }}
```

Docs: https://gohugo.io/templates/lists/#by-title